# Receive full PSObject (un-serialised) from remote session

Tags: c#, powershell

When using PowerShell remoting, returned objects are serialised resulting in a loss of fidelity of the PSObject. As result I cannot access properties at the depth I need to. Is there any way I can get around this, and receive the full PSObject?

Comment: It seems you can control the [serialization behavior including depth with PSStandardMember properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/05/01/object-serialization-directives.aspx). PSStandardMembers controls a number of internal behaviors for powershell, for example the [default members displayed in output](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/02/18/psstandardmembers-the-stealth-property.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get an un-serialized object from a remote session. The data stream between the sessions is SOAP.  This is HTTP/HTTPS, so it has to be serialized to a text stream.  You might be able to circumvent the limits on the default serialization depth by doing your own serialization on the remote side, and sending back the resulting text string, but if this is a follow-on to the previous question you posted you aren't going to have that option if you're connected to an Exchange management session.  Those are "No Language" constrained sessions, which means that the only thing you can do in that session is run the Exchange cmdlets. No other language elements or commands are allowed.

What properties are you needing to access that are being lost in the serialization/deserialization process?

Comment: Thanks for this info - I've decided I am going to give up on this path as it looks a little difficult for what I want to do. I'll probably look at writing a remote service toi execute on the local Lync/Exchange servers.